# How to plot the solution of an ordinary differential equation?

Tags: differential-equations

I want to know the graph of the ode

$\qquad \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2xy-x-1+\sqrt{(1+x)^2-4xy}}{2x^2} $

for $ x>0 $.

I just use the following codes:

```
sol = DSolve[y'[x] == (2*x*y[x] - x - 1 + Sqrt[(1 + x)^2 - 4*x*y[x]])/(2*x^2), y[x], x];
Plot[Evaluate[sol], {x, 0, 1}]
```

But it only gives me a frame with no graph. How can I plot this graph?

Answer (score 3):

Look at the form of `sol`.

```
{{y[x] -> 1/4 E^(-2 C[1]) (2 I + E^C[1]) (2 E^C[1] - 2 I x + E^C[1] x)},
 {y[x] -> 1/4 E^(-2 C[1]) (-2 I + E^C[1]) (2 E^C[1] + 2 I x + E^C[1] x)}}
```

`sol` is a replacement pattern containing the functional solutions, you can't plot it by itself. You can plot `y[x] /. sol`, which is `y[x]` with the solution substituted in.

It is also worth noting that you need a boundary condition to plot this graph, since there is an infinite family of functions that solve the differential equation by itself. You can add a boundary condition (such as $y(0)=3$), like so:

```
sol = DSolve[{y'[x] == (2*x*y[x] - x - 1 + Sqrt[(1 + x)^2 - 4*x*y[x]])/(2*x^2), 
    y[0] == 3}, y, x];
```

Alternatively, you can find the constants of integration in some other fashion and substitute them in directly, if you wish. Note that for many `C[1]` values, this will likely be a complex valued function, but it seems to have a purely real solution if the boundary condition is also real.

Then plot the result like so:

```
Plot[y[x] /. sol, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems. To plot it, you need to define the constants. Look at the answer and you'll see the answer has C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thg4X.png) in it, this needs a numerical value for the plot (I arbitrarily chose C[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Thg4X.png)->1.) Second, the answer is complex. Since you need to plot real numbers, I chose to take Abs to make it real.

```
Plot[Abs[(y[x] /. sol) /. C[1] -> 1], {x, -5, 5}]
```

[image]

You could also plot the real part with Re or the imaginary part with Im.